# replace javascript by jquery each() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I want to replace javascript to jquery to make `each()` to this function that show a single embedder tweet.

working version: https://jsfiddle.net/3u5r8e27/

```js
var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet1");
var id = tweet.getAttribute("tweetID");
twttr.widgets.createTweet(id, tweet, {});

tweet = document.getElementById("tweet2");
id = tweet.getAttribute("tweetID2");
twttr.widgets.createTweet(id, tweet, {});
```

```html
<script sync src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<div class='tweet' id="tweet1" tweetID="1262730246668922885"></div>
<div class='tweet' id="tweet2" tweetID2="1260658846143401984"></div>
```

Im trying this, but doesnt work. What am doing wrong?

```js
var tweet = 1;
var id = 1;
$(".tweet").each(function() {
  tweet = $(this).attr("id");
  id = $(this).attr("tweetid");
  twttr.widgets.createTweet(id, tweet, {});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script sync src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<div class='tweet' id="tweet1" tweetID="1262730246668922885"></div>
<div class='tweet' id="tweet2" tweetID2="1260658846143401984"></div>
```

Comment: Why does your second tweet have a `tweetID2`?  Why the #?

Comment: @taplar in the fiddle link, every tweet shows up, only if I call it from an unique id....now I want to call them by classes only.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Why does the second tweet need a unique attribute name for the tweetID?

Comment: In the javascript version, is needed to call the div by id, otherwise it doesnt work. in the jquery version, calling every div by class, nothing work

Comment: I'm not talking about the id.  I'm talking about the attribute names of `tweetID` on one and `tweetID2` on the other.  They are different and I'm asking why you needed that.

Comment: It is nonsense to change the attribute into `tweedID2`, and it's the only reason why you're having issues. Also, you don't need jQuery for this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/htr46ycp/

Comment: @ChrisG I liked your javascript version, I would like to mark it as an answer, but the question was about replacein it by jquery. I would definitely going to use your script!!+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, `tweet1` is a DOM element. In your jQuery code it's an ID. You need to get the element.

And change the DIVs to use the same attribute `tweetID`, not `tweetID` and `tweetID2`.

```js
$(".tweet").each(function() {
  var tweet = this;
  var id = $(this).attr("tweetID");
  twttr.widgets.createTweet(id, tweet, {});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script sync src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<div class='tweet' id="tweet1" tweetID="1262730246668922885"></div>
<div class='tweet' id="tweet2" tweetID="1260658846143401984"></div>
```

Comment: thnak you for the explanation, but it doenst work in the fiddle, or im doing something wrong again? https://jsfiddle.net/hymck5f9/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't import jquery.  Heh, also the fact that it works here and not in the fiddle, should self answer your question of "or im doing something wrong"

Comment: lol, I think Im the problem haha. ya thank you for the answer. it was very valuable!